# External Hardware Fingerprint scanner and android device integration

Tags: java, android, integration, fingerprint

I want to build an `android` application like employee attendance using `fingerprint` `scanner`. I want to know that,

1. Is it possible using external hardware device for fingerprint
   scanning?
2. How to integrate Android application with external hardware finger
   print scanning device.
3. How to fetch data from external hardware device and store data in local database.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution?.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible using external hardware device for fingerprint scanning?

Yes there's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to enroll and verify multiple users. For instance Samsung or iPhone only provide  SDK to verify 1 user (user of device) but others manufacturers provide an SDK to enroll and match multiple users.

> 2. How to integrate Android application with external hardware finger print scanning device.
> 3. How to fetch data from external hardware device and store data in local database.

Fingerprint scanners (quoted upper) have Android SDK to enroll and to verify. Some of ones only return fingerprint image. For fingerprint scanners only return image, you have to use external library to convert image to minutiae and enroll and verify as:

- http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm
- http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html

Comment: @user2028555, Is it useful ?

Comment: Why can't you use a Y-cable to charge and connect USB device at the same time? It's a thing you know.